# SpringMVC Serve JSP files from a Webcontent Folder using Java Configuration

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am converting a Struts2 Web Application to a Spring Web Application. In the process, I am converting the application from XML based to Java Configuration based. I am able to convert our RESTful Backend to spring WebServices, which work great. However, the entry point to the application needs to be through a jsp served by the server.

I am having trouble getting the Java to recognize the index.jsp that is located in the WEB-INF folder. I keep getting the error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I have tried configuring an InternalResourceViewResolver to point to the WEB-INF folder, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone see what I am missing, or doing wrong?

**WebInitializer.java**

```
public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){
    application.showBanner(false);
    application.sources(AppBaseConf.class);
    return application;
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException{

    super.onStartup(ctx);
}
```

**AppBaseConf.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppBaseConf extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppBaseConf.class);

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver(){
        logger.info("Configuring View Resolver");
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**PageController.java**

```
@Controller("pageController")
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value= "/home")
    public String showHomePage() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: do u have /WEB-INF/templates/index.jsp?

Comment: Yes. Opening the deployed war file and navigating to /WEB-INF/templates shows that index.jsp is there

Comment: set the springframework log level to debug and see where it is searching

Comment: How do I do that? I know I need to create a application.properties file, but where does this file go? (I dont follow the src/main/resource/ convention. I use gradles war plugin to add my properties, libs, webcontent, etc. separately)

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html can u find here?

Comment: What should I be looking for in the logs?

Comment: whether it is showing any info saying resource not found

Comment: The only thing I see, is Could Not Resolve Template "index"

Comment: can u change /WEB-INF/templates/ to /WEB-INF/jsps/ and create a jsps folder inside WEB-INF and place index.jsp there.